importing airflow automatically creates airflow directory
I've noticed that whenever I import airflow in Python, it automatically creates an airflow directory in my home directory. Literally just this
$ python
Python 3.11.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Apr 19 2024, 18:36:13) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'airflow'))
False
>>> import airflow
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'airflow'))
True

I understand that's because I don't have AIRFLOW_HOME set. So it appears airflow is using home directory as a default location if the AIRFLOW_HOME env var is not set.
But why is it doing that in the first place?  I'm just importing airflow library, without even beginning to do anything.
Is it possible to disable this behavior?

import in Python is not a declaration - it's an executable statement

I've checked the source code on github.
And as part of the configuration file there is a function called write_default_airflow_configuration_if_needed which tries to write the airflow.cfg file in the AIRFLOW_HOME. It has a mkdir call to create the parent directory.
This function is what creates your airflow folder. And there does not seem to be an option to stop it.
This makes sense since Airflow has a bunch of features and functions that need to look for items in the AIRFLOW_HOME such as DAGS, PLUGINS, the default database and a bunch of config files.
But if you really don't want airflow to create new folders, just assign an existing one as the AIRFLOW_HOME (cough cough /tmp)
